# getting data with checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to do a product filter in php via checkboxes, basically i could get it to display the products with one filter, but i am lost in how to make multiple checkboxes to work with eachother.

here's what i've tried:

the part where it changes the sql command

```
if (isset($_GET['checkDress'])){


if (empty($where)){
    $where=" where category = 'kleit'";
    }elseif(!empty($where)){
    $where.=" and category = 'kleit'";
    }

}

if (isset($_GET['nightDress'])){

if (empty($where)){
    $where=" where category = 'oKleit'";
    }elseif(!empty($where)){
    $where.=" and category = 'oKleit'";
    }


}
```

the sql command :

```
$res=mysql_query("select * from items $where $filter");
```

checking one of the checkboxes is fine, it returns the correct result, but checking 2 at the same time doesn't return anything at all. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Should it be `or` instead of `and`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems like the dresses cannot satisfy multiple categories simultaneously, it seems like you want to use `or` for the filter rather than `and`.  That would be a simple fix, but I think you can improve on this solution a lot.

```
<!-- pass filters as array -->
<input name="filter[]" type=checkbox value=kleit>
<input name="filter[]" type=checkbox value=oKleit>

$filters = $_GET['filters'];
$params = array_fill(0, count($filters), '?');
if ($params) {
    $where = "WHERE category IN (" . implode(',', $params) . ")";
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, i cannot believe it was that simple *facepalm* thanks a lot, it works. Would it be too much to ask for an explanation what exactly does your improved version do? looks greek to me >_> or at least a nudge in the right direction where i can learn about it?

Comment: @user2209644 for the html you can use arrays in CGI parameters (`$_GET` for example) with the bracket syntax.  So `name="filter[]"` means that `$_GET['filter']` is an array.  The `array_fill` creates an array of `?` for use in a parameterized query (e.g. with PDO): `array('?', '?')`.  If it's not empty, `$where` becomes `"WHERE category IN (?,?)"`.  Then you can call `$stmt->execute($filters)`

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
$where = " WHERE ";
$conditions = array();

if (isset($_GET['checkDress'])){
    $conditions[] = "category = 'kleit'";
}

if (isset($_GET['nightDress'])){
    $conditions[] = "category = 'oKleit'";
}

$where .= implode($conditions, ' AND ');
```

Maybe use `IN` instead of multiple `AND`,, or you may have different conditions, filters, etc...